# CSS - how to fix text appearing below containing div box?

Tags: html, css

my 'about me' and echoed 'about text' appear below the containing div(class="u-about"), for both of them, i have no idea why its doing this, and id rather not use relative positioning to move it up, as it seems messy, and it shouldn't be doing this in the first place. any idea's on how to fix this would be much appreciated!

my css code:

```
.profile-about { /* contains profile card and about card */
float: left;
}

.u-about {
position: relative;
top: 100px;
display: block;
width: 400px;
height: 220px;
background-color: white;
border-radius: 10px;
text-align: center;
margin: 0px;
}

.ubout {
margin: 0px;

}
```

my html code:

```
 <section>
  <div>
    <div class="profile-about">
    <div class="u-profile-card">
        <h3>Guide:</h3>
        <div>
          <h2><?php echo ucfirst($first);?> <?php echo $last; ?></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="img-txt">
        <div class="image-cropper">
        <img class="u-image" src="uploads/<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="no 
        image found">
        </div>
        <div class="u-info">
        <h2><?php echo ucfirst($u_city); ?>, <?php echo ucfirst($u_region); ? 
        >, <?php echo ucfirst($u_country); ?></h2>
        <h2><?php echo ucfirst($u_rating); ?> Stars</h2>
        <h2 class="u-email"><?php echo ucfirst($email); ?></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="u-about">
        <div>
          <h1>About me</h1>
          <p class="ubout"><?php echo ucfirst($about); ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: where do you want to put it?

Comment: inside the div with class "u-about" :)

Comment: Just remove its fixed height.

Comment: @akemedis check out the my answer.!!

Answer (score 0):

By the containing div, I assume you mean their direct parent `<div class="u-about">`. The elements do not actually appear below that... though they may well **appear** to, due to the fact that you have `top: 100px` on this element. Simply removing this will bring the entire `.u-about` element up the page, including both texts:

```css
.profile-about {
  /* contains profile card and about card */
  float: left;
}

.u-about {
  position: relative;
  /*top: 100px;*/
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 220px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
}

.ubout {
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 200px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <div class="profile-about">
      <div class="u-profile-card">
        <h3>Guide:</h3>
        <div>
          <h2>
            <?php echo ucfirst($first);?>
            <?php echo $last; ?>
          </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="img-txt">
          <div class="image-cropper">
            <img class="u-image" src="uploads/<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="no 
        image found">
          </div>
          <div class="u-info">
            <h2>
              <?php echo ucfirst($u_city); ?>,
              <?php echo ucfirst($u_region); ? 
        >, <?php echo ucfirst($u_country); ?>
            </h2>
            <h2>
              <?php echo ucfirst($u_rating); ?> Stars</h2>
            <h2 class="u-email">
              <?php echo ucfirst($email); ?>
            </h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="u-about">
        <div>
          <h1>About me</h1>
          <p class="ubout">
            <?php echo ucfirst($about); ?>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: i took the 'top: 100px;' out and it moved the text and u-about box up yes, but the text is still displayed below the box and not in it sadly

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```css
.profile-about { /* contains profile card and about card */
float: left;
}

.u-about {
position: relative;
display: block;
top:100px;
width: 400px;
height: 220px;
background-color: white;
border-radius: 10px;
text-align: center;
margin: 0px;
}

.ubout {
margin: 0px;
position: relative;
bottom: 200px;
}
.child{
    position: absolute;
    height: 320pxpx;
    margin: -100px 0 0 0px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <div class="profile-about">
    <div class="u-profile-card">
        <h3>Guide:</h3>
        <div>
          <h2><?php echo ucfirst($first);?> <?php echo $last; ?></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="img-txt">
        <div class="image-cropper">
        <img class="u-image" src="uploads/<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="no 
        image found">
        </div>
        <div class="u-info">
        <h2><?php echo ucfirst($u_city); ?>, <?php echo ucfirst($u_region); ? 
        >, <?php echo ucfirst($u_country); ?></h2>
        <h2><?php echo ucfirst($u_rating); ?> Stars</h2>
        <h2 class="u-email"><?php echo ucfirst($email); ?></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      
    <div class="u-about" style="background-color:red;">
         <div class="child">
           <h1>About me</h1>
           <p class="ubout"><?php echo ucfirst($about); ?></p>
         </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: i wanted to try and avoid relative positioning :/